# Service Fabric Cluster Upgrade Failing

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've an on-premise, secure, development cluster that I wish to upgrade.  The current version is 5.7.198.9494.  I've followed the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server).

At the time of writing, the latest version of SF is 6.2.283.9494.  However, running `Get-ServiceFabricRuntimeUpgradeVersion -BaseVersion 5.7.198.9494` shows that I first must update to 6.0.232.9494, before upgrade to 6.2.283.9494.

I run the following in Powershell, and the upgrade **does** start:

```
Copy-ServiceFabricClusterPackage -Code -CodePackagePath .\MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric.6.0.232.9494.cab -ImageStoreConnectionString "fabric:ImageStore"
Register-ServiceFabricClusterPackage -Code -CodePackagePath MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric.6.0.232.9494.cab
Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade -Code -CodePackageVersion 6.0.232.9494 -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
```

However, after a few minutes the following happens:

- Powershell IDE crashes
- The Service Fabric Cluster becomes unreachable
- Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager disappears from the task bar
- Event Viewer will log the events, see below.
- Quite some time later, the vm will reboot.  Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager will only give options to Setup or Restart the local cluster.

Event viewer has logs in the under Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft-Service Fabric -> Operational.  Most are information about opening, closing, and aborting one of the upgrade domains.  There are some warnings about a vm failing to open an upgrade domain stating error: Lease Failed.

This behavior happens consistently, and I've not yet been able to update the cluster.  My guess is that we are not able to upgrade a development cluster, but I've not found an article that states that.

Am I doing something incorrectly here, or is it impossible to upgrade a development cluster?

Comment: How many nodes does your cluster have? Did you try to upgrade to a version different from 6.0.232?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you have a development cluster with a single node or multiple nodes in a single VM.

As described in the first section of the documentation from the same link your provided:
[service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server)

> You can upgrade your cluster to the new version only if you're using a
>   production-style node configuration, where each Service Fabric node is
>   allocated on a separate physical or virtual machine. **If you have a
>   development cluster, where more than one Service Fabric node is on a
>   single physical or virtual machine, you must re-create the cluster
>   with the new version.**

Comment: How would one go about providing a different ClusterConfig for the local cluster when re-creating it?